# Button not showing up correctly in TableRow

Tags: android, layout

I am programmatically adding a `Button` in a `TableRow`. When I add the button, The button shows up where I want it to except that it looks like the button is shifted down. I want the button to be center aligned. Here is how I am adding the button to the table row, the xml with my Table Row, and a picture of what what my button looks like when I run my application

[image]

```
    public void addNewButtonToRegister(String buttonString, String buttonPrice, Button_Sizes buttonSize){
    Button newButton = new Button(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Button addButton = (Button) mMenuFragment.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    int height = addButton.getHeight();
    int width = addButton.getWidth();
    newButton.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(height, width));
    newButton.setText(buttonString + "\n" + buttonPrice);
    TableRow firstRow = (TableRow) mMenuFragment.findViewById(R.id.first_row);
    firstRow.addView(newButton);
}

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/test"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/first_row">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:text="@string/add_button"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/register_button_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/register_button_size"/>



    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and i designed based on weight concept and modify it according to your wish

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bgcolor"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dip" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24.5sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/locationsRowss"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvlocation11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Journey Date"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tvJourneyDate"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                android:gravity="left|center|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="2/3/2017"
                android:textColor="@color/vehicledetailcolor"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </TableRow>



</LinearLayout>
```